# React Native - Access properties of exported functional component

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here is my code for a custom functional component (./Animations/ModalViewMoveUp.js)

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Animated, Easing, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { ExtendedExceptionData } from 'react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox';

export const ModalViewMoveUp = (props) => {
  const moveAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(900)).current  
  const animIn = Animated.timing(
    moveAnim,
    {
      toValue: 50,
      duration: 1700,
      easing: Easing.elastic(),
      useNativeDriver:false
    }
  )
  const animOut = Animated.timing(
    moveAnim,
    {
      toValue: 1000,
      duration: 1700,
      easing: Easing.elastic(),
      useNativeDriver:false
    }
  )
    
  React.useEffect(() => {
    animIn.start();
  }, [moveAnim])

  
  return (
    
    <Animated.View                 
      style={{
        ...props.style,
        marginTop: moveAnim,         
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

And in ./App.js

```
import {ModalIconViewMoveDown} from './Animations/ModalIconViewMoveDown'
...
<ModalViewMoveUp >
  {/* other elements */}
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>???}><Text>CANCEL</Text></TouchableOpacity>

</ModalViewMoveUp >
```

I basically want a way to start the exit animation `animOut.start()` on when the cancel button is pressed, but i cant even get a `ref` of the `ModalViewMoveUp` element in the `TouchableOpacity` , let alone call a function from it.
Even something like this would work for me

```
<ModalViewMoveUp shouldStop={this.state.shouldStop}>
  {/* other elements */}
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setState{{shouldStop:true}}}><Text>CANCEL</Text></TouchableOpacity>

</ModalViewMoveUp >
```

And then in /ModalViewMoveUp.js

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
   if(shouldStop){
     animOut.start();
   }
    //animIn.start() runs on render()
  }, [moveAnim])
```

But i know i cant just set a state in an exported component.
Do i have to convert my functional component to a class?
Any code examples would be appreciated!

Comment: Consider `children` as function, i.e. a render prop for `ModalViewMoveUp` so that it can pass `animOut` as an argument when rendering child components. Also check out custom hooks but that might take more refactoring of your current set up.

Comment: So lets say i add this to /ModalViewMoveUp.js
 `props.shouldStop = ()=>{animOut.start();} `

How should i go about calling that in my App.js ?

Answer (score 1):

What i ended up doing: pass a state bool when calling the component

```
<ModalViewMoveUp shouldOpen ={this.state.shouldOpen } style ={styles.modalViewUp}>
  {/* other elements */}
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setState{{shouldOpen:true }}}><Text>CANCEL</Text></TouchableOpacity>

</ModalViewMoveUp >
```

and in /ModalViewMoveUp.js

```
return(
<View>
    {props.shouldOpen == true &&
    <Animated.View                 
      style={{
        ...props.style,
        marginTop: moveAnim,         
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Animated.View>
    }
    {props.shouldOpen == false &&
    <Animated.View                 
      style={{
        ...props.style,
        marginTop: moveAnim,         
      }}
    >
      {animOut.start()}
      {props.children}
    </Animated.View>
    }
    </View>
  );
)
```

It works exactly as i want it to. If anyone has any contraindications feel free to share !